# Интервал дат как параметр в SSRS

Tags: mysql, дата, select, ssrs

Имеется селект для отчета на MySQL. Отчет буду публиковать на SRSS.

```
select 
  DATE(r.request_date) "Дата",r.request_id "Код SRDL",
  concat('SR-',r.request_number) "Номер заявки", st.status_code "Статус заявки", 
  r.special_instructions "Инструкции",
  r.tm_price "Согласованная стоимость отправки"
from request r
  join request_status_history h on r.request_id =  h.f_request_id and
    r.last_status_id=h.rsh_id
  join service_status st on h.f_status_id = st.status_id
where 
  r.f_ct_id =1000118 and st.status_id=100 and 
  r.request_date between '2019-04-01' and '2019-06-01'
```

Как вместо дат задать входящие параметры: Дата с: и Дата по:??
Когда задаю даты как параметры, селект ничего не показывает.

Comment: "Когда задаю даты как параметры" - ??

Comment: Выразился не совсем правильно. Имел ввиду: последняя строка выглядит сейчас так:  where r.f_ct_id =1000118 and st.status_id=100 and r.request_date between (символ @)start_date и (символ @)end_date       . В start_date и end_date необходимо выбрать диапазон дат. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Т.е. сейчас отчет работает так: вводишь изначально в коде SQL диапазон дат и отчет выполняется. А мне надо чтобы я к примеру выбрал диапазон в SSRS с 01.01.2017 по 01.01.2018. Сейчас именно когда выбираю дату - отчет ничего не выдает.